# SVG created programatically by javascript not appearing

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a few sites where I'm creating an SVG programatically in JavaScript using `createElementNS`. It's always worked up until the present, but for some reason, on one project, it's not working.

[image]

You can see that the SVG registers in DevTools but has a screen height of 0x0. I'm wondering anyone has tips to debug it? The code is quite long that makes it & whenever I try to distill a minimal example it works, so I'm a bit stuck on what may be going on here. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is caused by the missing [`viewBox`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute. `createElementNS` is definitely the correct approach.

Comment: Typo in the namespace used in `createElementNS()`, maybe? Check that it says `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` (no `https`, no trailing slash, year is “2000”, ...).

Comment: @SebastianSimon I assume it’s something else. `viewBox` is not required. If not set a default value calculated from the content is used.

Comment: The problem doesn't occur when I type the blockquote lines shown in your image to the snippet generator here, nor when I load it to a browser from a text file, so the markup is functional as is. I can't reproduce, or imagine, a styling pattern that would cause it but feel looking at your style sheets might be a place to start?

Comment: It is indeed tricky, & I've also verified it in a snippet generator. What's even more infuriating is that minimal examples all work, it's just this page that's failing for some reason. I checked the [stylesheet](https://github.com/oxalorg/sakura/blob/master/css/sakura.css) and nothing leaps out that'd be causing this.